# Appropriate color model for image data of scanners for postprocessing, OCR, ...?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, post-processing

I am not really familiar with color models and how these formats affect software functionality. In case, *RGB* and *CMYK* are the only models I've used so far.

Basically, I am using a scanner to digitize, for example, newspapers. Especially old articles are often of a bad quality. I would like to postprocess them, like sharpening the characters, whitening the background, higher the contrast and so on. Finally, I would like to apply some OCR solution on the images.

Since I have no experience at such tasks, I would like to get some tips. I am familiar with OpenCV and other software as well as advanced programming skills in Python, Java, etc. Hence, this shouldn't be a problem.

However, I do not know what image formats would be appropriate for my project. **Does the color model matter at all here?** Is sharpening, for example with kernel filters, better on RGB images (where hue, saturation, and brightness are implicitly present in the red, green and blue channels)? Or is mixing color information with hue, saturation, and brightness a bad idea for postprocessing?

Comment: You can always convert between colourspaces later so that shouldn't be an issue. My suggestion would be to scan to 16-bit TIF so you have the maximum information for whatever processing you choose/develop down the line.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have some experience with this? Could you supply a qualitative answer on why TIF should be the best choice? Do you know if separate information on stuff like hue, saturation, brightness, ..., is important to postprocessing/OCR?

Comment: My skills and experience are in the area of satellite imagery, aerial and other photography. A high bit depth image is essential for enhancement and TIFs have always been the gold standard as far as I am concerned - every tool can read them and they have no artefacts that JPEG suffers from. As I said, you can convert to HSL/YUV and any other colourspace at any point down the line so it doesn't really matter which one you start with as long as you have the bit depth and resolution.